# how can if shortened with the same satisfying condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I shroten the condition because it has the same satisfying that greater than zero. Here is the code below:

```
a = 10
b = 5
c = 2

if a > 0 || b > 0 || c > 0
  puts "greater that zero"
else
  puts "it is zero or less than zero"
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably do

```
if [a, b, c].any? { |x| x > 0 }
  puts "greater that zero"
else
  puts "it is zero or less than zero"
end
```

Comment: `[a, b, cc].any? &0.method(:<)` :)

Comment: When ruby is the language you use on regular basis, it’s even more readable, than `{ |x| x > 0 }`.

Comment: @RajarshiDas excuse me?

Comment: @mudasobwa I like & learn  the code style u given  `&0.method(:<)` instead of `{ |x| x > 0 }` if possible please post an answer

Comment: @RajarshiDas it brings no added value, since it’s a shorthand / syntactic sugar to the answer above. I appreciate you liked it.

Comment: This will add some process. Instead of just doing `if` you add a loop.

Comment: I am surprised that ruby doesn't have `Numeric#positive?`

Comment: @mudasobwa: "since it’s a shorthand / syntactic sugar" - I'm sorry, but I think it's syntactic acid :) Must be I'm not as trained in reading those as you. Maybe it's a good thing. :trollface:

Comment: `[a, b, c].any?(&:positive?)` - now _that_ would be sugar.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev well, frankly I don’t like sweets and I _do_ like spicy much, maybe that’s the reason. I agree that `positive?` would be more sugary if we had it, but we haven’t :)

Comment: @mudasobwa that is a fancy approach. Can you explain the `&0.method(:<)` part? It's unconventional.

Comment: @maxpleaner it’s both conventional and idiomatic ruby. `any?` expects a block, `&` converts the `proc` argument to a block, [`Method#to_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Method.html#method-i-to_proc) converts instance method `Numeric#<` with receiver `0` to a `proc`.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
if [a, b, c].max > 0
  puts "greater that zero"
else
  puts "it is zero or less than zero"
end
```

Comment: One question: I think with `max` it has to pass through all the elements of the array, instead with `any?` at the first true it can exit and give the result. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Of course, you're right. But it also doesn't have any significance, I think, for this size array.

Comment: Sure, it's true :)

Answer (score 2):

I like to use Ternary operators for a true or false situation.

```
[a,b,c].any?(&:positive?) ? "greater that zero" : "it is zero or less than zero"
```

Some examples:
https://repl.it/CgZR/1

Comment: Correct. I mistakingly thought that all numbers should be positive.

Comment: positive? It doesn't exist

Comment: @Ursus try it in irb.

Comment: [Numeric#positive?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Numeric.html#method-i-positive-3F)

Comment: @Ursus you can see it in action with the [link](https://repl.it/CgZR/1) provided in the answer.

Comment: Oh I see. It doesn't exist in Ruby 2.2.x